# Javascript: compare user input to definition list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a game where the user is shown a number, and has to type the translation in french of that number. I am kinda stuck on how to do this:

In specific, I want to know how to create a list with the numbers and the definitions in french, which is easy to compare to the input given by the user. I was thinking of two different ways:

First, create two lists (e.g.: question = [1, 2, 3, 4] and answer = [un, deux, trois, quatre]) and then compare the user input to the indexes of the lists, so like thisL if user input is equal to some element in answer and the index of the element is the same index of the question that is asked, then it is correct.

However this seems not very efficient to me, so I came across javascript dictionary list. On this one I am however not sure how to compare the user input to this.

The user input is just a simple HTML input element.
I know this question is quite vague, I cannot really show any code since the main problem is just that I don't know where to start so I apologize for that.  JQuery solutions (if there are any) are also very welcome!

Comment: I assume you would like to use a hashmap

Comment: Any unclear things or open questions regarding my answer and what you asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple object like this (ES6 example code using `let` instead of `var` and template literal instead of string concatenation):

```js
let questions = {
  1: 'un',
  2: 'deux',
  3: 'trois',
  4: 'quatre'
}

let test = "1"

let answer = prompt(`Translate ${test}`)

alert(answer === questions[test] ? "Correct" : "Wrong")
```

ES5 version of that snippet:

```js
var questions = {
  1: 'un',
  2: 'deux',
  3: 'trois',
  4: 'quatre'
}

var test = "1"

var answer = prompt('Translate ' + test)

alert(answer === questions[test] ? "Correct" : "Wrong")
```

Note: jQuery is of no use here.